# Filtering a section in json data using Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

Need assistance only pulling / filtering "results" from json data as shown below

```json
[
{
    "reportSection": "Report Detail",
    "reportSections": [
        "Report Header",
        "Report Detail"
    ],
    "stats": {
        "returnedRows": 22,
        "userAllowedRows": 100000,
        "totalRows": 22
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "report_date": "05/31/2023",
            "report_begin_date": "05/31/2023",
            "report_end_date": "05/31/2023",
            "published_date": "05/31/2023 13:55:06",
            "office_name": "Minneapolis, MN",
            "office_city": "Minneapolis",
            "office_state": "MN",
            "market_type": "Point of Sale - Grain",
            "market_location_name": "Grain - South Dakota",
            "market_location_city": "Sioux Falls",
            "market_location_state": "SD",
            "slug_id": 3186,
            "slug_name": "AMS_3186",
            "report_title": "South Dakota Daily Grain Bids",
            "grp": "Grains",
            "cat": "Coarse",
            "commodity": "Soybeans",
            "location_State": null,
            "location_City": null,
            "trade_loc": "Central",
            "class": null,
            "grade": "US #1",
            "protein": null,
            "application": null,
            "pkg": "bulk",
            "desc": null,
            "quote_type": "Basis",
            "delivery_point": "Country Elevators",
            "conventional": "Conventional",
            "basis_unit": "¢/Bu",
            "sale Type": "Bid",
            "basis Min": 20,
            "basis Min Futures Month": "August (Q)",
            "basis Max": 30,
            "basis Max Futures Month": "August (Q)",
            "basis Min Change": 0,
            "basis Min Direction": "UNCH",
            "basis Max Change": 0,
            "basis Max Direction": "UNCH",
            "price_unit": "$ Per Bushel",
            "price Min": 12.3775,
            "price Max": 12.4775,
            "price Min Change": 0.0175,
            "price Min Direction": "DN",
            "price Max Change": 0.0175,
            "price Max Direction": "DN",
            "avg_price": 12.4108,
            "avg_price_year_ago": 16.3867,
            "freight": "Delivered",
            "trans_mode": "Truck",
            "current": "Yes",
            "delivery_start": null,
            "delivery Start Half": null,
            "delivery_end": null,
            "delivery End Half": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Only been successful at querying API and pulling back json data file in Python, but trying to learn how to pull out only a specific section of data and read to a data frame.  Example, data where Report Section = 'Report Detail' and bring back all 'results' rows

Below is python code attempted so far:

```
datapull = response_API.text
data = pd.read_json(datapull)

def section_results(record):
    section = record.get('reportSection', 'Report Header')
    result = section.get('results', None)

print([section_results(r) for r in data])

#data = pd.read_json(datapull)
#df = pd.Series(validate_record_schema(data)).to_frame()
#print (df)
```

Error I am getting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95zWW.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you need help with exactly? Like to start, do you know how to get this data into Python? e.g. you might use the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Then do you know how to select particular parts of it? Show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. See [ask].

Comment: There's an extra opening brace (`{`) which makes this JSON invalid. If that's just a typo, you can [edit] to fix it.

Comment: It is missing the opening and closing brackets [].  I tried to add, but wouldn't let me save as it wanted me to add more details

Comment: Ah yeah, the system doesn't want new users posting too much data/code. Try making a [mre] then.

Comment: I was able to modify, and did find the extra bracket you mentioned.  I was trying to minimize result set and didn't clean that up.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is string with Json data. You can use `json` module to parse it and then filter it to pandas DataFrame:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd


json_string = '''\
[
{
    "reportSection": "Report Detail",
    "reportSections": [
        "Report Header",
        "Report Detail"
    ],
    "stats": {
        "returnedRows": 22,
        "userAllowedRows": 100000,
        "totalRows": 22
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "report_date": "05/31/2023",
            "report_begin_date": "05/31/2023",
            "report_end_date": "05/31/2023",
            "published_date": "05/31/2023 13:55:06",
            "office_name": "Minneapolis, MN",
            "office_city": "Minneapolis",
            "office_state": "MN",
            "market_type": "Point of Sale - Grain",
            "market_location_name": "Grain - South Dakota",
            "market_location_city": "Sioux Falls",
            "market_location_state": "SD",
            "slug_id": 3186,
            "slug_name": "AMS_3186",
            "report_title": "South Dakota Daily Grain Bids",
            "grp": "Grains",
            "cat": "Coarse",
            "commodity": "Soybeans",
            "location_State": null,
            "location_City": null,
            "trade_loc": "Central",
            "class": null,
            "grade": "US #1",
            "protein": null,
            "application": null,
            "pkg": "bulk",
            "desc": null,
            "quote_type": "Basis",
            "delivery_point": "Country Elevators",
            "conventional": "Conventional",
            "basis_unit": "¢/Bu",
            "sale Type": "Bid",
            "basis Min": 20,
            "basis Min Futures Month": "August (Q)",
            "basis Max": 30,
            "basis Max Futures Month": "August (Q)",
            "basis Min Change": 0,
            "basis Min Direction": "UNCH",
            "basis Max Change": 0,
            "basis Max Direction": "UNCH",
            "price_unit": "$ Per Bushel",
            "price Min": 12.3775,
            "price Max": 12.4775,
            "price Min Change": 0.0175,
            "price Min Direction": "DN",
            "price Max Change": 0.0175,
            "price Max Direction": "DN",
            "avg_price": 12.4108,
            "avg_price_year_ago": 16.3867,
            "freight": "Delivered",
            "trans_mode": "Truck",
            "current": "Yes",
            "delivery_start": null,
            "delivery Start Half": null,
            "delivery_end": null,
            "delivery End Half": null
        }
    ]
}
]
'''

data = json.loads(json_string)

filtered_data = []
for d in data:
    if d.get('reportSection') == 'Report Detail':
        filtered_data.extend(d['results'])

df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  report_date report_begin_date report_end_date       published_date      office_name  office_city office_state            market_type  market_location_name market_location_city market_location_state  slug_id slug_name                   report_title     grp     cat commodity location_State location_City trade_loc class  grade protein application   pkg  desc quote_type     delivery_point  conventional basis_unit sale Type  basis Min basis Min Futures Month  basis Max basis Max Futures Month  basis Min Change basis Min Direction  basis Max Change basis Max Direction    price_unit  price Min  price Max  price Min Change price Min Direction  price Max Change price Max Direction  avg_price  avg_price_year_ago    freight trans_mode current delivery_start delivery Start Half delivery_end delivery End Half
0  05/31/2023        05/31/2023      05/31/2023  05/31/2023 13:55:06  Minneapolis, MN  Minneapolis           MN  Point of Sale - Grain  Grain - South Dakota          Sioux Falls                    SD     3186  AMS_3186  South Dakota Daily Grain Bids  Grains  Coarse  Soybeans           None          None   Central  None  US #1    None        None  bulk  None      Basis  Country Elevators  Conventional       ¢/Bu       Bid         20              August (Q)         30              August (Q)                 0                UNCH                 0                UNCH  $ Per Bushel    12.3775    12.4775            0.0175                  DN            0.0175                  DN    12.4108             16.3867  Delivered      Truck     Yes           None                None         None              None
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  How would I now pass an api response with a string to the json_string?  json_string = '''\ response '''

Comment: I got it to work.  data = json.loads(datapull) with datapull being the api response.  Thank you again very much.

Comment: @andrejkesely......How do I handle if a 'reportSection' does not have a 'results' section?

Comment: @mbjeter You probably check with `if-else` if the section is or isn't there and handle appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and I now have it working:

```
response_API = 
requests.get("https://marsapi.ams.usda.gov/services/v1.2/reports/3186? 
q=report_date=2023-05-31&allSections=true", 
auth=HTTPBasicAuth(api_key_string, ''))

print(response_API.status_code)

datapull = response_API.text
print (datapull)

data = json.loads(datapull)

filtered_data = []
for d in data:
    if d.get('reportSection') == 'Report Detail':
        filtered_data.extend(d['results'])

df = pd.DataFrame(filtered_data)
print(df)
df.to_excel("json_data_2.xlsx")
```

How would one suggest best way to read the list of 'reportSections' so that I can filter data for each section?